# Characterizing the RSK corespondance

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

The Robinson-Schensted-Knuth correspondence is an algorithm which takes as input a word $w$ on the alphabet $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of length $k$ and returns a pair of a tableau $P(w)$ and a standard tableau $Q(w)$ of the same shape and  of size $k$. This algorithm enjoys a lot of nice properties and is compatible with many operations on words and on tableau. While this algorithm is fairly easy to run on examples i find it hard to "recognize it" abstractly.

Basically I'm in the following situation: I have an algorithm which takes a word $w$ of length $k$ and produces a pair of a tableau $P'(w)$ and a standard tableau $Q'(w)$ of the same shape such that:

1. The weight of $P'(w)$ is the weight of $w$, i.e. the entries of $P'(w)$ are the letters of $w$ with the correct multiplicities.
2. For any word $w$ and any letter $i$, $Q'(w)\subset Q'(wi)$ so $Q'$ is "the recording tableau of the algorithm producing $P'$".
3. It coincides with RSK on Yamanouchi words.

My question is:

> How far am I to show that my bijection coincides with RSK ? Or at least to show that $Q=Q'$ ? Are there some general unicity results about the RKS correspondence ?

Comment: Do Knuth equivalent words give you the same P', and dual equivalent words give you the same Q'?